# How to debug Google Sign-in with expo framework?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-signin, google-drive-android-api

I am implementing the "Backup to Google Drive" feature to my mobile app based on react-native with expo framework.

I have tried already everything...this helped me at most: https://blog.expo.io/react-native-google-sign-in-with-expo-d1707579a7ce

Currently, I have a valid access token (firebase auth. works correctly), but it works only if the app is in standalone mode (builded APK).

Is there any way, how to debug my code? If I build it, I am not able to debug it anymore.

I don't want to eject from expo, but this feature is really important for me.

Comment: Android has its own debugging capability on Android Studio.

Comment: I understand... But how can I debug expo project? I know, that if i eject from expo to bare react native, than it is possible to use Android Studio... But is there any possibility, how to do that without ejecting?